# mysql command in command line return unknown variable

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze

When I try to use:

```
mysql -u [user] -p
```

command (or any other "mysql") at my Debian server command line I get this error:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'log=/var/log/mysql.log'
```

mysql-client is installed, the

```
general_log_file
```

line in my.cnf file is uncommented (I've found this tip on google) but I still get this "unknown variable" and I can't use mysql in command line.

Comment: What MySQL version you are using on Debian? Also what is your my.cnf file location?

Comment: Can you check the following? mysql --print-defaults and mysql --help --verbose. Can you also try mysqladmin variables?

Answer (score 0):

general_log_file is a mysql**d**, the server part of mysql, option.

However, it is not complaining about that. Check your my.cnf file for

```
log=/var/log/mysql.log
```

Under the client section

excerpt from [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: ... :: 4.2.6 Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html)

```
Be sure not to put an option in the [client] group unless it is recognized 
by all client programs that you use. Programs that do not understand the 
option  quit after displaying an error message if you try to run them.
```